# How to add extended information to a .Net Remoting call without adding new parameters on the calls?

Tags: remoting, .net-remoting

I am working with a large existing .Net Remoting service.  This service needs to be modified in a way that all calls to the service need additional information to allow the service to process the calls correctly.

I would like to avoid adding a new parameter onto each of the existing functions, and would prefer to pass extended information from the client to the server in a way that leaves the interfaces unchanged and still allows the service to process the calls correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be accomplished using the following interfaces:
IClientChannelSink, IClientChannelSinkProvider, IServerChannelSink, and IServerChannelSinkProvider

Using these interfaces, a client sink can be created, which can add the new global information onto each call as a header value, and the server sink can pull this header value off, and store it for usage by the logic code.

You can find a high level overview of these at http://www.diranieh.com/NETRemoting/ExtendingNET.htm

The client config section to enable your client sink is:

> ```
> <system.runtime.remoting>
>   <application>
>       <channels>
>             <channel ref="tcp" port="0" encryption="EncryptAndSign">
>               <clientProviders>
>                   <provider 
>                    type="Namespace.ClientSinkProvider, dll"/>
>               </clientProviders>
>           </channel>
>       </channels>
>   </application>
> </system.runtime.remoting>
> ```

The server config section to enable your server sink is:

> ```
> <system.runtime.remoting>
>       <application>
>           <channels>
>                <channel ref="tcp" port="0" encryption="EncryptAndSign">
>                          <serverProviders>
>                               <provider 
>                                type="Namespace.ServerSinkProvider, dll" />
>                               </serverProviders>
>               </channel>
>           </channels>
>       </application>
> </system.runtime.remoting>
> ```